# Formatting property in C#

Tags: c#, class, properties

I am currently studying for an exam, while I was trying to write a class I saw this requirement for a property.I need to write this property in class called User.

> Phone – must be in the format “+[country_code]/[phone]” where
>   [country_code] is between 1 and 3 digits and the [phone] is between 8
>   and 10 digits.
>
> - Valid phones: +123/88888888, +1/1234579284
> - Invalid phones: -123/88888888, +123/      4    5 4444444, +123348585313,
>     +123\34553363587

Do I use `[RegularExpression()]` from `ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` or something else?

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 0):

I think that this code does what you want:

```
private string _phone;
public string Phone
{
    get
    {
        return _phone;
    }
    set
    {
        int indexOfSlash = value.IndexOf("/");

        if (value.Length > 13 || indexOfSlash > 4 || indexOfSlash < 2 || value[0] != '+')
            throw new Exception("Wrong format");

        for (int i = 1; i < value.Length; i++)
        {
            if ((i < indexOfSlash || i > indexOfSlash) && !value[i].IsDigit())
                throw new Exception("Wrong format");
        }

        _phone = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is a good example why it makes sense to use regular expressions: Once you are familiar with the syntax, their's much better to read and maintain than code like this.
You can simplify this code a little:
indexOfSlash > 4 || indexOfSlash < 2 => indexOfSlash != 3
i < indexOfSlash || i > indexOfSlash => i != indexOfSlash
Also, the code crashes if the phone number is an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression in the setter of the Phone property.

```
^\+\d{1,3}\/\d{8,10}$
```

Breaking this down:

- `^`: Match only at beginning of the string.
- `\+`: Matches +, this needs to be escaped.
- `\d{1,3}`: Matches any digit (0-9) from 1 to 3 times.
- `\/`: Matches /, this needs to be escaped.
- `\d{8,10}`: Matches any digit (0-9) from 8 to 10 times.
- `$`: Match only at end of the string.

Example code:

```
private static Regex phoneRegex = new Regex(@"^\+\d{1,3}\/\d{8,10}$", RegexOptions.Compiled);

private string phone;
public string Phone {
    get { return phone; }
    set {
        Match match = phoneRegex.Match(value);
        if (match.Success) {
            phone = value;
        } else {
            throw new ArgumentException("value");
        }
    }
}
```